# Extract elements from List string built using c #

Tags: c#, list, split, webforms

I have this string

> Dispatching System,proposal,to be
> sent,main,2022-006,related,2022-017,related

that is composed of this c# code

```
List<string> value1 = new List<string>();
foreach (string item in Request.Form)
{
    if (item.Contains("ddl"))
    {
        value1.Add(Request.Form[item]);
    }
}
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('value1:\\n" +
    string.Join(",", value1) + "');", true);
```

Using the code above the output is

> Dispatching System,proposal,to be
> sent,main,2022-006,related,2022-017,related

Now I need to extract from this string from element number 5 to all subsequent elements, that is

> 2022-006,related,2022-007,related

and storing a row for each string value in a database table, that is

| t | q |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-006 | related |
| 2022-017 | related |

**Expected output**

```
2022-006 
related 
2022-017 
related
```

But the **expected ouput** now is empty...

This is my c# code

```
List<string> value1 = new List<string>();
foreach (string item in Request.Form)
{
    if (item.Contains("ddl"))
    {
        value1.Add(Request.Form[item]);
        List<string> value2 = item.Split(',').ToList();

        for (int i = 4; i < value2.Count; i++)
        {
            //Insert into db
            Response.Write(value2[i] + "<br />" + value2[i + 1] + "<br /><br />");
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help, really appreciated.

**Solution**

```
List<string> value1 = new List<string>(); 

foreach (string item in Request.Form)
{
    if (item.Contains("ddl"))
    {
        value1.Add(Request.Form[item]);
    }
}

var requestDLL = string.Join(",", value1);
var value2 = requestDLL.Split(',');

for (int i = 4; i < value2.Length; i++)
{
    //Insert into db
    Response.Write(value2[i] + "<br />" + value2[i + 1] + "<br /><br />");
    i++;
}
```

**Output**

```
2022-006 
related 
2022-017 
related
```

Comment: "But the expected ouput is empty" but then you list the two dates, so it's not empty. What is the requirement, it's not so clear?

Comment: The sample input doesn't have `"ddl"`, but you expect it to be there; can you provide something that actually should work and doesn't? It doesn't seem like there's anything wrong with your code.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'm sorry I've edited the question...

Comment: What does the *form* look like? Instead of trying to parse fields you could use model binding and get a list of strongly typed items as an action parameter. What stack are you using? WebForms? MVC? Razor Pages? `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` was only used in WebForms

Comment: @Luaan I'm sorry I've edited the question...

Comment: If you use WebForms and data binding you can bind directly to strongly typed objects *and* access the selected ones

Comment: A point from earlier still stands. The input you show does not contain the substring `ddl` meaning you aren't ever getting into the loop.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Using WebForms

Comment: What controls are you using? Where does `ddl` come from? If you use a `ListBox` or CheckBoxList for example and bind to a list through `DataSource`, the selected elements in the `Items` property will have will have `Selected = true`

Comment: In any case, writing directly to the response doesn't mean you'll end up with valid, visible HTML. You may be writing text right after the `</html>` tag for example, or inside a non-visible element. If you view the page source in your browser I suspect you'll find the generated text in the wrong place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can find the code that return the expected output  https://dotnetfiddle.net/8aBrZj

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var requestDLL = "Dispatching System,proposal,to be sent,main,2022-006,related,2022-017,related";
        
        var value2 = requestDLL.Split(',');

        for (int i = 4; i < value2.Length; i++)
        {
            //Insert into db
            Console.Write(value2[i] + "\n" + value2[i + 1] + "\n \n");
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest reading [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). This doesn't answer the question. It's not even uncommented code, it's just a link to somewhere without any explanation

Comment: Is based on the code from the question. I fix the code from the question

Comment: This answer fixes nothing. There's no code, no explanation. It's just a link to a site with code that will disappear after a while